# Get git remote info using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, git

I have to get remote git information using NodeJS. I have managed to get info from a cloned repo using [simple-git](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-git). The code I have test is the following:

```
require('simple-git')('/my/local/git/repo/path')
    .pull()
    .tags(function(err, tags) {
       console.log("These are my tags: %s", tags.all);
});
```

However, it requires the repo to be locally cloned. Is there any way (using this or another module) to connect the remote git to get this info?

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the path to any valid repo or leave it empty considered git repo is under current directory. That's just required to make commands worked.

After that you can use `listRemote` method in the following way:

```
require('simple-git')([optional path])
   // .init() - in case it's totally empty folder
  .addRemote('remote_repo_alias', 'path/to/remote/repo')
  .listRemote(['--tags', 'remote_repo_alias'], function(err, tags) {
    // ...
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to read the repo information without the having it locally cloned

Comment: @Genzotto updated an answer with `listRemote()` (underlying `git ls-remote`)

Comment: @OIeg Meleshko, I have tested it but it still gets me the info of the current repo, not the new one specificated in the addRemote function

Comment: @Genzotto that's bc you need to specify remote repo name as a second argument to `listRemote` method. See updated answer